# Cannot write where clause with rails includes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with this query?

```
PayorGroup.all.includes(payor_group_coverages: %i[cpt_code icd10_code],payors: [:payor_cpt_codes_settings],policies: {policy_coverages: %i[cpt_code icd10_code]}).where("payors.id = ?", 1) .references(:payors).limit(10)
```

Comment: What's the error when you run this query in a Rails console?

Comment: i guess `cpt_code` and `icd10_code` are attributes, right ?  remember that `#includes` works with association names not the attribute names.

Comment: I don't get any error for this query. But it is very slow, it takes up to 20-30 seconds to run the query. Even though I am running this locally and don't have much data.